# express ln(x) with a = 3 as taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I couldn't figure out how to represent $$ln(x)$$ with a=3
as Taylor series in summation form.

Comment: How about constructing a Taylor series of $y=ln(x+1)$ around $x=2$?

Comment: Do you know how to begin by writing it in the general form of a Taylor series involving powers of $(x-3)$, higher order derivatives of $\ln(x)$ evaluated at $x=3$ and factorial denominators? That should be your first step. Then you should find the higher order derivatives and evaluate them at $x=3$.

Comment: @ John Wayland Bales  I do, I worked out all those you mentioned, I just got stuck earlier trying to figure out how to construct the Summation form. My answer below cancels the Factorial, if you do the Taylor expansion then do the cancellation you will see the final answer is the one below.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$\begin{align}\ln(1+x)&=\int_0^x\frac1{1+t}dt\\&=\int_0^x\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-t)^ndt&\text{geometric series}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^xt^ndt\\\color{purple}{\ln(1+x)}&\color{purple}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}x^{n+1}}\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}\ln(k+x)&=\ln\left(k\left(1+\frac xk\right)\right)\\&=\ln(k)+\color{purple}{\ln\left(1+\frac xk\right)}\\&=\ln(k)+\color{purple}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\left(\frac xk\right)^{n+1}}\\\ln(k+x)&=\ln(k)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{nk^n}x^n\\\end{align}$$

Let $k+x\to x$ and see that we get the Taylor expansion of $\ln(x)$ centered around $k$:

$$\ln(x)=\ln(k)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{nk^n}(x-k)^n$$

Comment: Would you elaborate a little more on how you got from the summation to your last step as a Taylor series?

Comment: @Tmm Note the first half of the post with integral gives the power series of $\ln(1+x)$.  Let $x\to\frac xk$ to get the power series after than, and then let $x+k\to x$ to get the last statement.  I've tried to color code it to make it more obvious.

Comment: @ Simple Art I got that part, thanks for the color coding.

Answer (score 1):

$$ln(3)+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3^{n}n}(x-3)^{n}$$

Comment: Yes, that is the correct answer since you get a factor of the form $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}$.

Comment: @ John Wayland Bales Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=\ln(x+3)$

and $ \;f(x)=\ln(x)=g(x-3)$.

$$g(x)=\ln(3)+\ln(1+\frac{x}{3})$$

$$=\ln(3)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\frac{x^k}{3^k}+O(x^n)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$${\displaystyle \log(1+x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1}{\frac {x^{n}}{n}} \quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1}$$
let $x\rightarrow \frac{x}{3}$
$${\displaystyle \log(1+\frac{x}{3})=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1}{\frac {x^{n}}{n3^n}} }$$
$${\displaystyle \log(\frac{x+3}{3})=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1}{\frac {x^{n}}{n3^n}} }$$
$${\displaystyle \log(x+3)=\log 3+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1}{\frac {x^{n}}{n3^n}} }$$
let $x\rightarrow (x-3)$
$${\displaystyle \log(x)=\log 3+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1}{\frac {(x-3)^{n}}{n3^n}} }$$